# Can MQTT (such as Mosquitto) be used so that a published topic is picked up by one, and only one, of the subscribers?

Tags: mqtt, publish-subscribe

I have a system that relies on a message bus and broker to spread messages and tasks from producers to workers.

It benefits both from being able to do true pub/sub-type communications for the messages. 
However, it also needs to communicate tasks. These should be done by a worker and reported back to the broker when/if the worker is finished with the task.

Can MQTT be used to publish this task by a producer, so that it is picked up by a single worker?

In my mind the producer would publish the task with a topic "TASK_FOR_USER_A" and there are X amount of workers subscribed to that topic.
The MQTT broker would then determine that it is a task and send it selectively to one of the workers.

Can this be done or is it outside the scope of MQTT brokers such as Mosquitto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQTT v5 has an optional extension called Shared Subscriptions which will deliver messages to a group of subscribers in a round robin approach. So each message will only be delivered to one of the group.

Mosquitto v1.6.x has implemented MQTT v5 and the shared subscription capability.

It's not clear what you mean by 1 message at a time. Messages will be delivered as they arrive and the broker will not wait for one subscriber to finish working on a message before delivering the next message to the next subscriber in the group.

If you have low enough control over the client then you can prevent the high QOS responses to prevent the client from acknowledging the message and force the broker to only allow 1 message to be in flight at a time which would effectively throttle message delivery, but you should only do this if message processing is very quick to prevent the broker from deciding delivery has failed and attempting to deliver the message to another client in the shared group.

Normally the broker will not do any routing above and beyond that based on the topic. The as mentioned in a comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56128387/504554) answer the Flespi has implemented "sticky sessions" so that messages from a specific publisher will be delivered to the same client in the shared subscription pool, but this is a custom add on and not part of the spec.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, MQTT is not meant for this purpose. It doesn't have any internal working to distribute the tasks on workers (consumers). On the Otherhand, AMQP can be used here. One hack would be to conditionalize the workers to accept only a particular type of tasks, but that needs producers to send task type as well. In this case, you won't be able to scale as well.

It's better if you explore other protocols for this type of usecase.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a message broker for a producer/consumer scenario. MQTT is a lightweight messaging protocol which is based on pub/sub model. If you start using any MQTT broker for this, you might face issues depending upon your use case. A few issues to list:

1. You need ordering of the messages (consumer must get the messages in the same order the producer published those). While QoS 2 guarantees message order without having shared subscriptions, having shared subscriptions doesn't provide ordered topic guarantees.
2. Consumer gets the message but fails before processing it and the MQTT broker has  already acknowledged the message delivery. In this case, the consumer needs to specifically handle the reprocessing of failed messages.
3. If you go with a single topic with multiple subscribers, you must have idempotency in your consumer.

I would suggest to go for a message broker suitable for this purpose, e.g. Kafka, RabbitMQ to name a few.